# print maximum values of each pair of columns

Tags: r, row, max

I am sorry if I am asking the question if it has already been asked, but I could not find it..

```
AGE<-c(25, 37, 57, 72, 48, 28, 31, 57, 43, 38)
LLS<-c(24,  1, 24, 24, 14, 21,  4, 12,  8,  1)
RLS<-c(11,  1, 14, 21,  7, 21, 22,  8, 27, 12)
dat <- data.frame(AGE, LLS, RLS)
```

and want to get the maximum values of column `LLS` AND `RLS` for each rows.

Please can you tell me how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, dat[-1])
#[1] 24  1 24 24 14 21 22 12 27 12
```

If this is for each pair of columns, you can use `combn`

```
res <- combn(names(dat),2, FUN=function(x) do.call(pmax,dat[x]))
colnames(res) <- apply(combn(names(dat),2),2, paste, collapse="_")
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that for each row, you want to return a single value, whichever is higher of RLS or LLS. Right?

If so, Akrun's answer is good. Alternatively you can use the handy rowMaxs() function in the matrixStats package. In my opinion it's a little more straightforward, but that's the only real advantage.
Here is code, you can combine into fewer steps, but I wrote it out to make it clear what is going on.

```
AGE<-c(25, 37, 57, 72, 48, 28, 31, 57, 43, 38)
LLS<-c(24,  1, 24, 24, 14, 21,  4, 12,  8,  1)
RLS<-c(11,  1, 14, 21,  7, 21, 22,  8, 27, 12)
dat <- data.frame(AGE, LLS, RLS)
```

Create a subset of your dataframe, including only the columns you want

```
dat2 <- dat[,2:3]
```

Turn the new dataframe into a matrix so rowMaxs() doesn't complain

```
dat3 <- as.matrix(dat2)
```

Load the matrixStats package and call rowMaxs()

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMaxs(dat3)

[1] 24  1 24 24 14 21 22 12 27 12
```